# Angularjs data binding between controller and service

Tags: angularjs

I'm not able to get the data binding between controller and service working. 
I have a controller and a factory which makes an HTTP call. I would like to be able to call the factory method from other services and see the controller attributes get updated. I tried different options but none of them seem to be working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d3c16z?p=preview

Here is the javascript code.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.controller('EventDetailCtrl', ['$http', 'EventDetailSvc', '$scope',
    function ($http, EventDetailSvc, $scope) {

      this.event = EventDetailSvc.event;

      EventDetailSvc.getEvent();
      console.log(self.event);

      $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
        console.log('under watch');
        console.log(this.event);
        return this.event;

      }), function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('under watch2');
        console.log(newVal);
        this.event = newVal;
      });

    }])

  .factory('EventDetailSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var event = {};
    var factory =  {};

    factory.getEvent =  function() {
      $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com')
        .then(function (response) {
          this.event = response.data;
          console.log('http successful');
          console.log(this.event);
          return this.event;

        }, function (errResponse) {
          console.error("error while retrieving event");
        })
    };

   factory.event = event;

   return factory;

  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have nested the event object inside of a factory object. You should be returning event directly instead wrapping it with factory. As it stands now you would need to call EventDetailSvc.factory.event to access your object.